# Bind mouseenter and mouseleave events to multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of elements `div.teaser` that each contain a video wrapped with mediaelementplayer. On mouseenter and mouseleave I want the video to play `media.play` and stop `media.stop` respectively.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="teaser">
    <a href="#">
       <video>...</video>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="teaser">
    <a href="#">
       <video>...</video>
    </a>
</div>
[... and so on]
```

The problem is that if I hover any of the elements they all fire the event. Current jquery is:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    features: [],
    loop: false,
    enableAutosize: true,
    alwaysShowControls: false,
    iPadUseNativeControls: false,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: false, 
    AndroidUseNativeControls: false,
    alwaysShowHours: false,
    showTimecodeFrameCount: false,
    pauseOtherPlayers: true,

    success: function(media, domElement, player) {      
        $(".teaser").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                media.play();
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                media.stop();
            }

        });

    } // Success     
}); // mediaelementplayer
```

At a guess I need to tell the function to bind to `$(this)` `div.teaser`. I've tried a number of options but none seem to stick.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snerone/e62bb70d/13/)

Comment: Where is `.teaser` relative to the `video` tag?

Comment: @matthew `.teaser` wraps the `video` tag. Post updated with html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
$(".teaser").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).find('video').media.play();
});
```

you could show the html that would make it easier...

EDIT: here you go

```
$(".teaser").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).find('video').get(0).play();
});
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work. I've added html to my post.

Comment: @Seb #Seb .. try same but video.play() .. does that work for you?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that still doesn't work. The error I get in the console is that `$(this)` isn't defined. So the script doesn't know which element to attach it to.

Comment: @Seb can you put a jsfiddle and link to it, we can try get it right :)

Comment: your help is much appreciated. [JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/snerone/e62bb70d/13/)

Comment: @Seb here you go $(".teaser").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).find('video').get(0).play();
});

Comment: You – are – a – star. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you have this div#video, which contains all these div.teaser. You can attach an event listener like this

```
$('#video').on('mouseenter', 'div.teaser', function() {
  //do media play
});

$('#video').on('mouseleave', 'div.teaser', function() {
  //do media stop
});
```

To get the div.teaser object use $(this) inside the function